Updating Profile Image in Next.js with NextAuth Session and Cloudinary: Changes Not Reflecting Instantly
In my Next.js app, I'm using NextAuth for user sessions and storing the profile photo in the session after updating it via Cloudinary upload. Despite the backend updating the image and reflecting the new URL in the session, the UI doesn't instantly update the image due to browser caching issues. I attempted to force refresh by appending a timestamp to the image URL on the client side, but the change still doesn't reflect immediately. Below is the relevant code snippet, handling the image upload, user profile update, and UI attempt to display the new image.
I tried updating the user's profile image using Cloudinary in a Next.js application and expected the new image to be immediately reflected in the user interface. I appended a timestamp to the image URL to bypass browser caching. However, despite these efforts, the updated image does not show up without a manual page refresh.
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import image2 from "@/assets/images/fondo.webp";
import logo from "@/assets/images/logo-gum.webp";
import DarkButton from "@/app/client/components/DarkButton";
import SignoutModal from "@/app/client/components/SignOutModal";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  // Your code continues...
  const imageUrl = session?.user?.profileImage || 'URL_IMAGEN_POR_DEFECTO';
  const uniqueImageUrl = `${imageUrl}?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`;

  return (
    <div className="w-10 rounded-full z-[-1]">
      <img
        `alt="Tailwind CSS Navbar component"
        src={uniqueImageUrl}`
      />
    </div>
  );
};


Someone resolved this by adding a key to the Image component: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18369
